# Pulling percentage video viewed youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm going to create the automate API for youtube report. Is there a way to pull the number of users of each percentage (25%,50%) or second of video viewed via youtube analytics API? I use python language from link as shown below:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/data_model

I found a metric name "audienceWatchRatio", but I'm not sure that's what I want or not? I tried to run the script including this metric with and without "elapsedVideoTimeRatio" dimension, and it always shows "The query is not supported."

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found here in the [Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/) on how to get the percentage viewed in the video. By using the [`averageViewPercentage`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#averageViewPercentage) you will get the average percentage of a video watched during a video playback. The only problem here is this parameter get the total percentage of the channel, not the specific or individual video.

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/youtube%20analytics/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&start-date=2013-01-01&end-date=2017-02-04&metrics=averageViewPercentage&_h=4&) if you want to check on how to use this parameter.

I also found a related question about your issue, but this question uses Javascript. So just check if it can help and give idea to you.

[Calculate percentage of youtube video viewed with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775207/calculate-percentage-of-youtube-video-viewed-with-api)

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question. I'm not sure that data from youtube analytics API is organic or not ?