# Watch Time in Youtube Using Api

Tags: php

Is it possible to find watch time  of any YouTube video through YouTube API? If yes than how? If no, then please tell any alternative to it. Thanks.

Comment: refer this link 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_watch_history

Comment: I want How much time user view the video, and also Number of Subscribes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775207/calculate-percentage-of-youtube-video-viewed-with-api

Comment: You want a lot but what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it at your side rather then get from api.
when ever video play you have to start timer against that video is pause you have to pause the timer so on if navigate to other video you have to store the timer value.Hope you get my point .Thanks

Comment: I Want  time when User Watch a video in Youtube

Comment: yes you can do it as i mentioned before.Api will not give you such sort of info.

Comment: Yes ! hope fully that can be fetch :)

Comment: any Suggestions??ie Link or anything

Comment: Hope you have got it :) Thanks

Comment: Video played by these api are add up to watch time increase?